# HTML mailto function with icon class

Tags: php, javascript, html, mailto

I'm making a mail icon which could send emails of different contents stored in arrays.
the problem is, the contents are isolated using a loop:

```
foreach ($table as $data) {
echo '<a id="email-content" href="mailto:?body='.$data->content.'"><i class="icon-envelope" ></i></a>';
echo "<div class='search-tmp-div' style='display:none;'><pre class='search'>$data->content</pre></div>";
}
```

I was wondering if there is anyone I can use the function without the envelope icon printing out a bunch of times. I want it to print only once?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are many, an example of an alternative way would be:

1. create the icon button
2. create an html table
3. in each row, you put a column with a checkbox or radio box (for selection)
4. upon clicking on the icon button, you get the selected row(s) and send the requested email(s)

### Edit:

An example of what you need would be:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btn").click(function () {
                selector = "content-"+$("input[type=radio]:checked").val();
                location.href = "mailto:?body="+$("#"+selector).text();
            });
        });
</script>
<?php

$table = array( array( "id" => 1, "content"=>"content 1") , array( "id" => 2, "content"=>"content 2"), array( "id" => 3, "content"=>"content 3"), array( "id" => 4, "content"=>"content 4") );

echo '<img id="btn" src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Primo_Icons/PNG/128x128/email_send.png" width="40px" style="cursor:pointer;" />';
foreach ($table as $data) {
    echo "<div class='search-tmp-div' style='display:block;'>";
    echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"content\" value=\"{$data['id']}\">";
    echo "<pre class='search' id=\"content-{$data['id']}\">{$data['content']}</pre></div>";
}
```

Comment: please elaborate abit more about what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($table as $data) {
echo "<a id="email-content" href="mailto:?body='.$data->content.'">";
if($count == 0){ echo '<i class="icon-envelope"></i>';}
echo "</a><div class='search-tmp-div' style='display:none;'><pre class='search'>$data->content</pre></div>";
$count++;
}
```

This just adds a counter initially has a value of `0`, thus printing `<i class...></i>` on the first loop (where `$count == 0`).

Comment: thanks for the good and simple response! It worked, I was wondering with the mailto function, is there anyway I could send the file as an attachment rather than in the body? To make it less messy.

Comment: I've run into a little bit of problem with this new coding, as the original mail icon only corresponds to the very first value.